# 405 Access Error on Google-Translate-Free NPM Package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use the `google-translate-free` NPM Package, however everytime I attempt to use it, I constantly get the 405 Forbidden Error message.

Here is my code:

```js
const translate = require('google-translate-free');
await translate("Привет!", { to: "en" });
```

Here is the full error:
https://hastebin.com/oqusuwosuy.xml

Comment: `google-translate-free` seems to be a lesser-known fork of [this package](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api)

Comment: @Daniel_Knights that is correct, but that package is currently broken